# file cannot be deleted error showing file is open in the java su binary close the file and try again

Tags: java, xml, xls

i want to delete the file or copy the file created by this program which it is not allowing me need solution

```
package xml2html;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class Xml2HtmlConverter {

public static void main(String[] args, String xmlpath) {
    pathmethod(xmlpath);
}

public static void pathmethod(String xmlpath) {
      try {
        /* converting the file using xls */
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Source xslDoc = new StreamSource("D:/xmlautomation/stylesheet.xsl");
        Source xmlDoc = new StreamSource(xmlpath);

        String outputFileName = "D:/xmlautomation/output.html";
        OutputStream htmlFile = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslDoc);
        transformer.transform(xmlDoc, new StreamResult(htmlFile));

      } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where in your code do you try to delete which file?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args, String xmlpath)` ???

Comment: i added a little ui using html for browsing the xml file and sending the file path to servlet and from there to the above class and after conversion i redirect the page to another html showing conversion is sucessful

Comment: i found the answer and thanks for spending your valuable time in looking in to my problem @nfechner

Comment: @Flavio thanks for spending your valuable time in looking in to my problem i found the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package xml2html;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class Xml2HtmlConverter {

public static void main(String[] args, String xmlpath)
{
    pathmethod(xmlpath);
}

public static void pathmethod(String xmlpath) 
{
try
    {
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Source xslDoc = new StreamSource("D:/xmlautomation/stylesheet.xsl");
        Source xmlDoc = new StreamSource(xmlpath);

        String outputFileName = "D:/xmlautomation/output.html";
        OutputStream htmlFile = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslDoc);
        transformer.transform(xmlDoc, new StreamResult(htmlFile));
        htmlFile.close();     
    }

catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

finally
{

}
}
}
```